# Fruitful? Fruitless? Fruitempty? Fruitmore?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, suffixes

I notice that the word fruitful's opposite is fruitless.

It's kind of bizarre. Figuratively speaking, if the activity produces no fruit, it is fruit-less. But if it does produce fruit, shouldn't it be fruit-more?

And vice-versa, if the activity producing many fruit is fruit-ful(l), shouldn't an activity producing few/no fruit be fruit-empty? Or some other suffix for empty?

Comment: English is not logical. It is what it is.  I might similarly argue that it should be *fruitsome* to match *toothless, toothsome*

Comment: @Jim: I trust you're being facetious. *Toothsome* does not mean "having teeth", but "tasty".

Comment: The answer to the question is: "No, it shouldn't be something else. It is what it is." One of the [basic properties of derivational morphology](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf) is that it is irregular and does not form paradigms. It's **inflectional** morphology that's regular and forms paradigms, but English only has 9 inflectional morphemes left in the whole language, though hundreds of derivational ones like _-hood, -ship, -ful, -less, in-, re-, dis-, .._ remain. Each follows its own regular irregularities and hasta be learned individually. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "less" suffix there is not a comparative, but from the Old English suffix "-leas" meaning "to be without, lacking".

Comment: Compare with _loose_, which is related and makes more intuitive sense than comparing it to _less_ the comparative.

Comment: This answer is most explanatory and makes the most sense. Understanding the origin of the suffix explains a lot. Does the 'ful' suffix still mean the same thing today as it did before? (full of)